# Why do I get strong name validation failed for assembly?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, strongname

Why do I get strong name validation failed for assembly?

It is a c++\cli dll.  We have it set to use our strong key - the same one we use for all of our projects.

```
sn -T example.dll
```

gives us

`Public key token is ...` (the same token we get for all of our dlls )

But when we run

```
sn -vf example.dll
```

We get:

```
Failed to verify assembly -- Strong name validation failed for assembly ...
```

Any ideas of what I should look for?  This is build in Visual Studio 2013 with our strong key name specified in the project properties pages.

**Update - answers to questions posed by Hans:**

The key file is setup using the project's "Property Pages" in Visual Studio.

```
KeyFile: $(SolutionDir)Keys\Ivara.snk
```

The platform toolset is: Visual Studio 2013 (v120)

For the manifest question - I am not 100% sure, but from the property pages:

Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Command Line gives:

/verbose /out:".\x64\Debug\oqkern.dll.embed.manifest" /nologo ".\x64\Debug\oqkern.dll.embed.manifest.res"

**Hans' suggestion worked:**

I marked the dll as delay signed and I added a post build step to do the signing:

```
sn -R "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)Keys\Ivara.snk"
```

After this:

```
C:\Development\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Debug>sn -vf oqkern.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly 'oqkern.dll' is valid
```

Comment: There were problems with it in the past.  At a minimum describe *exactly* how you specified the key file, the project's Platform Toolset setting and whether you do anything special with the manifest.

Comment: I have updated the question with the answers to your questions.

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  The only other thing you can do is delay-sign the assembly when you build it and run sn.exe afterwards to sign it.

Comment: This works, feel free to make an answer if you want and I will select it.

Comment: To me it looks like we only have this problem with c++\cli dlls.